# Ubuntu 16 stop lightdm and start xinit/xterm

Tags: linux, ubuntu, x11, xorg

I am working with Ubuntu 16. I have been able to stop the desktop environment using:

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

Now I would like to start, from another terminal in a console environment, the X server just to start one application in order to check CPU performance.

However, I have not been able to start it properly. Firstly, I export the DISPLAY variable, whose exact value I don't know. For instance, this does not work:

```
export DISPLAY=':0'
```

And then I execute xinit or xterm. In the latter case, I get the following error:

```
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: :0
```

I have configured xorg.conf but not .xinitrc. What is it supposed to be done to do what I need (i.e. start a kind of kiosk mode Linux) ?

Comment: what about `startx` with properly set `.xinitrc`? (see `man startx` for examples and explanation)

Comment: Editing /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc did the trick. However, each time the machine is started still starts the desktop environment. I have to stop the lightdm service and launch `xinit` as root.